# MS Access frontend with SQL Server backend query storing best practices

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, view, parameters, common-table-expression

I am trying to move to better optimized organization of my project. Using MS Access as frontent and SQL Server as backend my goal is to separate as much as it is possible, follow best practices and bring ability to use different / multiple frontends (web, c#, python). To achieve my goals I decided to follow some design decisions:

- store as much complicated queries in backend using views as it is possible
- do as much processing in the backend using stored procedures as it is possible
- quit using linked tables and switch to generating recordset in the VBA code using short and simple queries.

Playing arround with some popular features of SQL Server I found problems that I cannot resolve by my self.

- CTE can be parametrized. Views cannot. What about CTE stored in a view? If the answer is NO then is there any other convenient way to store CTE server side and call it from VBA to build recordset? What about other parametrized queries?
- Writing complicated queries in MS Access as the VBA code is pain in the... fingers and eyes. Maybe there is any other way to store queries like a boss in Access?
- How do You organize your frontend - backend app especially if the frontnend is MS Access and it is intended to be moved to any other platform?

TYA
Smok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CTE has zero zero to do with having parameters or not. A CTE is simply the same idea as writing a query on a query (or now a view on a view). In place of having to write (and save) two views? You can use a CTE.

However, where a CTE is most useful? Especially in a Access context?
Well, one of the REALLY REALLY nice features of Access SQL is that aliased columns can be re-used in expressions in that sql. With T-SQL syntax, you cannot!. And the result is horrid ugly T-SQL.

Take this typical query (Access SQL) nice (simple + easy) query in Access:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Company, State,
    (SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Purchases where Customer_ID = Customers.ID) as Purchased,
    (SELECT SUM(Payment) FROM Payments where Customer_ID = Customers.id) as Payments,
    (SELECT TaxRate from TaxRates where State = Customers.State) as TaxRate,
    (Purchased - Payments) as Balance,
    (Balance * TaxRate) as BalanceWithTax
```

As you can see? In the above, we use a sub query to get purchased, Payments, and the TaxRate. Then we use these 3 in expressions.
But, with T-SQL (sql server), we can't use the aliased columns.
So, you get this now:

```
SELECT ID, Company, State,
(SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Purchases where Customer_ID = Customers.ID) as Purchased,
(SELECT SUM(Payment) FROM Payments where Customer_ID = Customers.id) as Payments,
(SELECT TaxRate from TaxRates where State = Customers.State) as TaxRate,
((SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Purchases where Customer_ID = Customers.ID) - 
(SELECT SUM(Payment) FROM Payments where Customer_ID = Customers.id)) as Balance,
( (SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Purchases where Customer_ID = Customers.ID) - 
(SELECT SUM(Payment) FROM Payments where Customer_ID = Customers.id)) * 
(SELECT TaxRate from TaxRates where State = Customers.State) as BAlanceWithTax
FROM Customers
```

And the above is a SIMPLE example. So in above, t-sql does NOT allow re-use of columns in expression (like Access SQL does). So, the above, or say converting Access SQL to T-SQL is a royal pain - just outright painful.

So, we can use a CTE in t-sql to "tame" the above. We can go:

```
WITH MyCTE
AS
(SELECT ID, Company, State,
(SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Purchases where Customer_ID = Customers.ID) as Purchased,
(SELECT SUM(Payment) FROM Payments where Customer_ID = Customers.id) as Payments,
(SELECT TaxRate from TaxRates where State = Customers.State) as TaxRate
FROM Customers)

SELECT ID, Company, State, Purchases, Payments, TaxRate,
       (Purchases - Payments) as Balance,
       ( (Purchases - Payments) * TaxRate) as BalanceWithTax
         from mycte
```

Now, note how we STILL had to repeat the balance expression, but at least we could NOW use the calculated columns in FURTHER expressions without having to repeat them.
So, CTE's are a GREAT feature to help you convert all those AMAZING queries in Access SQL that "very nicely" has this ability to repeat (re-use) any Alised expression in T-SQL.

As for CTE's and parameters? They have ZERO ZERO connection to each other. And CTE's don't support or have parameters any more or less then anything else in t-sql. (so there is no connection between CTE's and parameters I can see here).

But, the answer to the question? Can you use CTE's in a view? YES you can, and there is little reason not to. Before CTE's then you could use a few tricks, or (gasp) simple create one view, save it, and then create another view on that. So, a CTE is really JUST a simple way to do a query on query without having to create a separate view to query against.

But, all in all, a CTE can be used as a view, and the MAJOR reason why is because T-SQL is missing that lovable ability of Access SQL that allows re-use of aliased columns where as T-SQL does not. So, the issue of CTE's is especially important when trying to convert Access SQL to T-SQL - it gets you back this wonderful ability that Access has in sql, and a feature you will sorely miss in T-SQL syntax.

> Writing complicated queries in MS Access as the VBA code is pain

Well, I can't say in-line sql in code in say .net or most other languages is all that clean either. You tend to be using string concatenation, and that always a challenge, but I can't say doing so in say .net development as opposed to VBA is much better.
However, in most cases?

Put the sql text as a saved query in Access, and thus use that in your code.
So, running with our above example?

You could have this in code:

```
dim strSQL    as string
strSQL = "SELECT ID, Company, State," & _
"(SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Purchases where Customer_ID = Customers.ID) as Purchased," & 
"(SELECT SUM(Payment) FROM Payments where Customer_ID = Customers.id) as Payments," & _
"(SELECT TaxRate from TaxRates where State = Customers.State) as TaxRate," & _
"(Purchased - Payments) as Balance," & _
"(Balance * TaxRate) as BalanceWithTax " & _

dim rst     as DAO.RecordSet
set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordSet(strSQL)
```

Can't really say the above is any worse then say writing above in most other languages.
But, of course one could (and in Access VBA typical would) save that query, and thus the above code becomes ONE LINE of code.

eg:

```
set rst = CurrentDB.OpenRecordSet("qryGetBalance")
```

So, ugly in-line sql in VBA can certainly be "tamed" by saving such queries as opposed to writing them out in code. I can't say .net is any better if you using in-line sql (and since you have to deal with a connection object, command object, and in most cases a data adaptor? Well, then that .net code becomes MORE wordy and takes MORE code then the one line of code in VBA to do the same thing.

Ok, so that address your CTE issue and that of in-line and using SQL in VBA code.

As to organizing the FE in Access? Well, for the LEAST amount of work for the best performance? Without question views are the way to go. The reason is Access plays very nice.

If you have a form in Access. Say bound DIRECTLY to a linked table. Before sql server, that form would be bound to the accDB back end.

Assume 1 million rows.
Assume access back end is a shared accDB in a folder.
Assume the form is based on this linked table.

So, how in the past would you launch + load and display ONE record, and ONLY pull one record down the network pipe?
Well, you don't launch the form UNLESS you pass it a where clause.

You do this:

```
dim strInvoice   as string
strInvoice = InputBox("Enter invoice number")
docmd.OpenForm "frmInvoices",,,"InvoiceNum = " & strInvoice
```

Well, now Access will ONLY pull ONE record down the network pipe. Not the whole table.

Now, assume that we migrated the BE tables to SQL server?
Now, assume we STILL linked the invoice form to that linked table of 1 million rows.
And of course the data is now in sql server.
How to pull ONLY ONE row down the network pipe?
You can use this:

```
dim strInvoice   as string
strInvoice = InputBox("Enter invoice number")
docmd.OpenForm "frmInvoices",,,"InvoiceNum = " & strInvoice
```

(same code). Access as a client will STILL only pull ONE row. This is despite the form being based directly on the linked table. So, as a general rule, access does not pull the whole table. It did not with a access back end (BE), and it does not if you have a linked table and a form bound directly to that linked table of 1 million rows.

There is not a lot of consideration here in regards to using Access as a FE to sql server, and that you have in the "future" say to use .net or now these days some web based development approach.

The only real tip and issue is that you don't really need to or can much adopt use of parameters from Access to sql. but with the Access where clause, then you rare need to anyway (so, yes, use the "where" clause of the open form/report in Access to obtain stealer performance, and limit network data pulled to the access client. So while most development platforms live and die around parameter based sql? Access is simply not one of these cases. You live and die (use lots) the concept of the where clause in Access, since it plays nice with SQL server and achieves the goal of only pulling data down the network pipe that you tell Access to grab/get by using the where clause of open form/report.

Where you can get the "most" re-use? Well, yes, for complex Access (client side) queries? Yes, move them to view. For some queries that become rather complex, then you can use a stored procedure in Access. (that means a pass-though query).

So, in access, say we had a complex invoice retrieval that involved complex joins, lots of queries? Then you could create a stored procedure, and then from access use this to get data:

```
with CurrentDB.queryDefs("ptGetIvnoice")
   .SQL = "Exec GetInoice " & strInvoice
   rst = .OpenRecordSet
end with
```

Once again, 4 lines of code. So, one REALLY nice tip is that be you writing code in VBA, or .net or whatever? Don't have in-line connection string code. As you can see in above, in that VBA, we do not have ANY connection string in code - nor is it required even in above when consuming a T-SQL stored procedure.

So, yes, using views means that your asp.net or whatever system you eventually adopt allows you to use the same views you saved SQL Server side, and thus access, or the web or any other software can use the same views.

The other issue is that access will play nice with views, and you RARE need to adopt stored procedures in T-SQL for parameter based queries. The reason of course is that Access has that "where" clause as I noted above. There are no T-SQL parameters, and adding criteria to a linked view in access (where clause) will perform on par with a stored procedures, but without missay parameters that Access does not support well in the first place.

So, views are near tops in Access development, since Access plays so nice with them, and also this means that such views can be re-used when you adopt say asp.net or whatever if your goal(s) are eventually to re-place Access. However, Access really does make a great RAD tool when your back end is sql server. So you achieve a good level of scalability when you do this, better security, and of course to have asp.net or even other desktop development platforms consume that data. Often after moving the Access data to sql server, companies will find little need to drop access, since all those forms, reports, and code can continue to be used while say a web based technology is adopted.

Comment: Wow. This is amazing. You've put a lot of effort in this answer and I appreciate it very much. You pointed some very important topics that I didn't even realize and din't understood. CTE was my main point because of using recursion in few of my queries. I just wanted to use params to control the level of recursion start. This answer definitely made my mind clearer about the subject. Once more thank you very much for your patience and clear explanations.